# Getting two values with two different WHERE

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, sum, greatest-n-per-group

So I'm trying to get one value which is the MAX number of a name from one state and then the total of that name from all states.
I think I have to do a `WHERE * IN` but don't know what to put there. This is what I have so far

```
SELECT name,SUM(number) as total
FROM
`bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
where state = 'AL'
group by name;
```

Comment: I tried to do 

WHERE name = ( max(number) from `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
where state = 'AL') but ofcourse that doesn't work because its a string.

Comment: how result will look like? share example of expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
select name, sum(number) total
from bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current t
where name = (
    select name
    from bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current
    where state = 'AL'
    order by number desc
    limit 1
)
group by name
```

The subquery recovers the `name` that has the greatest `number` for state AL. Then, the outer query computes the sum `number` for that name across the whole dataset.

Comment: oh, okay I understand where I messed up on the "where name = " part thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, 
  SUM(IF(state = 'AL', number, 0)) count_in_AL,
  SUM(number) total_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count_in_AL DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

with result

```
Row name    count_in_AL total_count  
1   James   158827      5015584
```

which means : James is the most popular name in AL (with 158,827) and with total across all states as 5,015,584